# errors when using the bluetooth sample code on android developer site

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I am working to add Bluetooth capabilities to my app and ultimately the device that I want to use is a headset/earpiece. I have begun assembling the code and I partial functionality with it. When I got to the code for setting up a bluetooth connection by server, I got errors when adding the code. I have tried solving the problems through the hover over the error and autocorrect but every time I fix one problem a different on arises. This leads me to believe that I am missing something that autocorrect doesn't know about. I need some help fixing the errors. Useful suggestions for setting a bluetooth codin for the first time would also be appreciated. Errors are surrounded with ||#| xxx |||. Error 1:cannot be resolved.  Error 2:cannot be resolved to a variable. Error 3:undefined for the type AcceptSocket.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothServerSocket;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;

public class AcceptSocket extends Thread {

    private static final String MY_UUID = null;

    BluetoothServerSocket mmServerSocket;


    public void AcceptThread() {
        // Use a temporary object that is later asssigned to mmServerSocket,
        // because mmServerSocket is final
        BluetoothServerSocket tmp = null;
        try {
            // MY_UUID is the app's UUID string, also used by the client code
            tmp = ||1|mBluetoothAdapter|||.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(||2|NAME|||,
                    MY_UUID);
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
        mmServerSocket = tmp;
    }

    public void run() {
        BluetoothSocket socket = null;
        // Keep listening until exception occurs or a socket is returned
        while (true) {
            try {
                socket = mmServerSocket.accept();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                break;
            }
            // If a connection was accepted
            if (socket != null) {
                // Do work to manage the connection (in a separate thread)
                ||3|manageConnectedSocket|||(socket);
                mmServerSocket.close();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    /** Will cancel the listening socket, and cause the thread to finish */
    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmServerSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Srry, I forgot that it the underlined errors don't show up when I past code. I will surround the underlined areas with||| xxx  |||

Answer (score 1):

Error 1,2: There is no constant called `NAME` anywhere in the class.

Error 3: There is no method called `manageConnectedSocket()` in the class.

You can't just copy and paste something from the developer's page and expect it to work.  It leads you in the correct direction and you have to fill in the missing pieces.

Comment: Okay, but if you read my question completely, I said I have tried adding those things in and I get alternate errors. For example: On error 1 and 2 when I add the constants I get an error on listeningusingrfcom.... that says I need to add a cast to bluetoothadapter but that doesn't work

Comment: @SamBevins Your UUID is null.  You need to give it a valid UUID before it can attempt to open a BluetoothSocket.  I would recommend reading more about how the Bluetooth protocol and Sockets work in general before trying to implement this.

Comment: Also, the BluetoothChat application has a good example to look at.

Comment: It should be somewhere in your Android folder.